# Pull URL via Screenflow in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to pull the URL for whatever record the user is on when they launch my screenflow.

For example if they are on an account I would need the account URL:
"https://mydomain--partial.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Account/00000000000000/view"

If they are on a report, I would need the report URL:
"https://mydomain--partial.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Report/00000000000000000/view?queryScope=userFolders"

My screenflow launches from a utility action.

I'm using the following formula in the screenflow now
`(LEFT({!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_260}, FIND( '.com', {!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_260} )) + RIGHT({!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_260}, FIND( '.com', {!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_260} )))`

The problem is that this returns:
"https://mydomain--partial.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/26.0/00000000000"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question and wanted to share just in case anyone came across this in the future.

What I had to do was:

1. Call the flow in an aura cmp
2. Get the window location in the cmp and pass it to an input variable in the flow

CMP:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <lightning:flow aura:id="FLOW NAME"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
  init : function (cmp) {
      
    var flow = cmp.find("FLOWNAME");
     var inputVariables = [
        {
            name : 'vCurentlURL',
            type : 'String',
            value : window.location.href,
        }
     ];
    flow.startFlow("FLOWNAME", inputVariables );
  }
})
```